# iOS push notifications don't receive

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Here's my code for receiving push notifications in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        registerForPushNotifications(application: application)
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }

        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
            if (granted)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        })

    }
```

I run my application in Time Profiler (cmd+I). App received token and then I copied that and use in pushtry.com. pushtry said% "Push Notification sent Successfully". But no notification is received :(

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/)